# Why CentOS 8 upgrade removes kernel files?

Tags: centos8

I have ran `sudo dnf update -y` on CentOS which is few months old.
I had this amongst other stuff it was doing:
[image]

I am sure its nothing to worry about (right?) but would like to know why is that and is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot and confirm the system comes back up. Restarting is necessary after core libraries like kernel and libc are updated, and a good idea after other updates as well.

Read `man dnf.conf` regarding the config option `installonly_limit`. Certain `installonlypkgs` always install, never upgrade, and so have multiple versions at once. kernel is on this list by default, enables recovery in case of a bad kernel update. Default limit is 3, as too many consumes disk space with obsolete packages.

Comment: yeah it reboots ok. thanks for the config tip